# E(XY) rule is inconsistent as $E(X^2)≠E(X)^2$?

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value, independence

There is an established rule that for two discrete independent variables $X$ and $Y$:

$E(XY)=E(X)\cdot E(Y)$

Thus, from this, I would reason that it is possible to say:

$E(X^2)=E(X\cdot X)=E(X)E(X)=E(X)^2$

However, it is not the case that $E(X^2)=E(X)^2$, which can be seen with many examples.

So, could anybody explain why this is the case? I am thinking that, because the $E(XY)$ rule applies to only independent variables, $X$ is dependent on itself, and thus the rule does not work?

Comment: You write "There is an established rule that for two discrete independent variables $$ and $$."  If $X=Y$, is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are two discrete independent variables?

Comment: One _informal_  way to think about independence of $X$ and $Y$ is that $X$ does not give you any information about $Y$. Now, does $X$ give information about itself?

Comment: Thank you for the comments everyone. 

I was following @Miguel's informal viewpoint when trying to rationalise this. So it is simply the fact that $X$ is dependent on itself.

Comment: Yes,  If you know the value of $X$, that tells you the value of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$ is dependent on itself so you cant use this property.
however, $$E[x^2]=\text {var}(x)+E^2[x]$$